# Name for smuggled liquor?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a name for liquor that might have been produced legally, or using professional technologies, but then has been smuggled, either bypassing customs, or into prohibition area and/or is being sold illegally?

"Moonshine" is the common name for suspicious quality liquor made using makeshift, illegal still, but that usually implies local, unprofessional production.
"Contraband" is the general name for smuggled, illegal goods, not just liquor.

Comment: 'bootlegged' is a more informal adjectival version of 'contraband', capturing everything you want except the idea of liquor.

Comment: @Mitch: I would have thought *bootleg* was exactly right (liquor is certinly the origin).  Why not make that an answer?

Comment: Bootleg can apply to things other than liquor. Bootleg recordings from concerts, for example.

Comment: I believe *moonshine* originally meant *smuggled liquor* in England, but the meaning changed at some point in early American English. See [this dictionary of slang](http://books.google.com/books?id=hrATAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA350&dq=moonshine+smugglers&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oOPET9unMIqQ9gTgs6S8Cw&sqi=2&ved=0CEoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=moonshine%20smugglers&f=false) from 1896. Since both illegal distilling and smuggling are generally thought of as night-time activities, the name is appropriate for both.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **bootlegged**

describes anything that is reproduced and distributed informally but illegally (similar to 'black market'). Currently it is almost always applied to music or movie recordings, either recorded live by an unofficial source or copying the medium and redistributing  against regulations. In the past, it was primarily associated with liquor production and distribution during the American Prohibition era, but [the word originated earlier](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bootleg) referring simplify to hiding a flask in the leg of one's boot.

Comment: I agree, but please note that *bootleg* is much more common than *bootlegged*.  (Google Ngram: http://goo.gl/E2C6o)

Answer (score 6):

**Hooch** is used to refer to [illicit liquor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Hooch).

> "Whisky or any strong liquor, esp if illicitly made or acquired" (Chambers)

Similarly, **moonshine** could refer to either illicitly distilled or smuggled liquor.

> "Smuggled or illicit spirit." (OED)
>
> "Spirits illicitly distilled or smuggled (chiefly N American)" (Chambers)

Comment: Does this refer to *smuggled* alcohol or more to illicitly-distilled liquor?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Could be both illegal preparation or acquisition.

Comment: I would say that hooch and moonshine both imply illicitly made

Comment: I'm pretty sure the name "Moonshine" comes from "distilled in the moonlight", usually an illicit, homemade outdoor still operating at night somewhere deep in the wilderness. Not brand quality alcohol smuggled bypassing tax and customs.

Comment: @SF. Etymologies and meanings are totally different; see this link: http://writinghood.com/style/grammar/eight-words-which-have-completely-changed-their-meaning-over-time/

Comment: @SF: Before its use in the U.S., the word moonshine [(see this 1896 dictionary of slang)](http://books.google.com/books?id=hrATAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA350&dq=moonshine+smugglers&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oOPET9unMIqQ9gTgs6S8Cw&sqi=2&ved=0CEoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=moonshine%20smugglers&f=false) was used in the U.K. for smuggled liquor, where it presumably meant "imported in the moonlight" (although nobody knows the etymology for certain).

Answer (score 2):

Isnt the word you want Contraband? That means illegal goods quite often alcohol or duty free products being smuggled?http://www.just-drinks.com/news/contraband-alcohol-seized-on-way-to-uk_id104802.aspx

Comment: I think contraband, like bootleg, has taken on a much broader meaning recently; the OP wants something that *only* means illegally obtained liquor.

Answer (score 0):

I've met a nice euphemism to describe this:

> Excise-free liquor

The fact that the excise tax is bypassed illegally is conveniently omitted.